# How to draw grids in Java

Tags: java, operating-system, scheduling

I have a project in Java.

The project is to show the scheduling algorithms (FIFO, Round Robin, SPN, SRT) in java using GUI.

Please guide me which library should I use? My aim is to produce an Output like in the following images.

http://www.utdallas.edu/~ilyen/animation/cpu/program/aview.gif
https://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/scheduling-toolbox/manual/img/fps_example.png

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Swing. It comes with the JDK.

Comment: Please elaborate a little more.

Comment: Here is oracle's tutorial on how to use Swing:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/